# SpriteBuilder and parallax

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, parallax, spritebuilder

Is there a way to get parallax going in the wysiwyg SpriteBuilder?

I am assuming for now that there is no way to do it, except change things around in code: define for instance a Level as decendant of CCParallaxNode instead of CCNode, then remove+readd stuff to the node, defining the parallax ratios.

(side note: there is no tag for cocos2d-iphone version 3)

Comment: correct, parallax is not currently built into spritebuilder

Comment: It's a pity because of the great wysiwyg side of SpriteBuilder... Surely parallax is one of those things where a GUI editor could be of use.

Comment: yup, I'd like that too, opened an issue here (I believe I've already seen it mentioned that it's planned or on the roadmap): https://github.com/spritebuilder/SpriteBuilder/issues/446